# App stuck in an infinite loop with 100% CPU usage - Seeking help to identify the cause and clarify our intention

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I am facing a puzzling issue in my iOS app, and I need some assistance in understanding the reason behind an infinite loop that is causing 100% CPU usage. I'll provide a brief explanation of our app's intention and share the relevant code snippet to help you understand the context.

Intention of the App:
Our app aims to create a visually appealing and interactive UI using SwiftUI. It involves a horizontal stack (HStack) containing three views: two "ReactanceView" elements on the left and right sides, and a "DraggingView" in the center. The "DraggingView" can be dragged horizontally, and we intend to adjust the width of the left and right "ReactanceView" elements accordingly, making them grow and shrink as the user drags the center view.

Issue Description:
Unfortunately, while implementing this feature, we encountered an issue where the app gets stuck in an infinite loop. As a result, the CPU usage spikes to 100%, and the app becomes unresponsive. Despite extensive debugging, we are struggling to pinpoint the exact cause of the infinite loop.

Relevant Code Snippet:
Here's the relevant code snippet for the SwiftUI views involved:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var xMovement: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ReactanceView(width: 100 + xMovement, color: .blue)
            DraggingView(xMovement: $xMovement)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        // Record the x-axis movement when the drag occurs
                        xMovement = value.translation.width
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        // Reset the x-axis movement when the drag ends
                        xMovement = 0.0
                    }
                )
            ReactanceView(width: 100 - xMovement, color: .blue)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ReactanceView: View {
    var width: CGFloat
    var color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        // Replace this with your custom reactance view (e.g., Text, Image, etc.)
        Text("Reactance")
            .padding()
            //.frame(width: width, height: 100) // <---- uncommenting this will couse infinite loop
            .background(color)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

We are reaching out to the Stack Overflow community for help in identifying the root cause of the infinite loop and the 100% CPU usage issue. We have thoroughly reviewed the code and verified that there are no apparent infinite loops or recursive functions. Additionally, we have ensured that the loop termination conditions are appropriately set for the DragGesture.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your issue using a dummy implementation of `DraggingView`.

My guess is that the `HStack` is having problems re-arranging when the views changing size (the `ReactiveView`) are in the same container as the view being dragged (the `DraggingView`). This is because, when DraggingView is dragged it has an impact on the width of the ReactiveView, but changing the width of a ReactiveView has an impact on the position of the DraggingView in the HStack, so there is inter-dependency.

You could try moving the view being dragged to its own layer, like this:

```swift
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ReactanceView(width: 100 + xMovement, color: .blue)
            // Reserve space for the dragging view in the overlay
            DraggingView(xMovement: .constant(.zero)).hidden()
            ReactanceView(width: 100 - xMovement, color: .blue)
        }
        .overlay {
            DraggingView(xMovement: $xMovement)
                // gesture modifiers as before
        }
        .padding()
```