# How to implement in SwiftUI to resize view in a HStack next to each other with drag?

Tags: swiftui

I would implement this:

[image]

My attempt, but it uses 100% of the CPU.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var xMovement: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var completed: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ReactanceView(width: 100 + xMovement, color: .blue)
            DraggingView(xMovement: $xMovement)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        // Record the x-axis movement when the drag occurs
                        xMovement = value.translation.width
                        completed = false
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        // Reset the x-axis movement when the drag ends
                        //xMovement = 0.0
                        completed = false
                    }
                )
            ReactanceView(width: 100 - xMovement, color: .blue)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ReactanceView: View {
    var width: CGFloat
    var color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        // Replace this with your custom reactance view (e.g., Text, Image, etc.)
        Text("Reactance")
            .padding()
            .frame(width: width, height: 100) // <---- uncommenting this will couse infinite loop
            .background(color)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}

struct DraggingView: View {
    @Binding var xMovement: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        // The view in the center that will be dragged
        Text("Drag me!")
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(Color.green)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .offset(x: xMovement, y: 0)
            .animation(.easeInOut)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App stuck in an infinite loop with 100% CPU usage - Seeking help to identify the cause and clarify our intention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76846411/app-stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-with-100-cpu-usage-seeking-help-to-identify-the)

Answer (score 0):

This is surely the same issue as your question [App stuck in an infinite loop with 100% CPU usage - Seeking help to identify the cause and clarify our intention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76846411/20386264).

This time you have also provided an implementation of `DraggingView`, which helps. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76846506/20386264) I gave before still holds:

```swift
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ReactanceView(width: 100 + xMovement, color: .blue)
            DraggingView(xMovement: .constant(.zero)).hidden()
            ReactanceView(width: 100 - xMovement, color: .blue)
        }
        .overlay {
            DraggingView(xMovement: $xMovement)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        // Record the x-axis movement when the drag occurs
                        xMovement = value.translation.width
                        completed = false
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        // Reset the x-axis movement when the drag ends
                        //xMovement = 0.0
                        completed = false
                    }
                )
        }
        .padding()
```

Comment: It works, but it is just seems a bit weird, DraggingView is not in HStack but over it

Comment: Yes, it is above the space that is reserved for it in the HStack by the hidden placeholder. If DraggingView always has a fixed size then you could use a simpler placeholder (such as a Rectangle) instead of a hidden instance of DraggingView. By putting the view-being-dragged above the HStack, instead of in it, it ensures there is no interdependency between views. This was presumably the cause of your looping.